# using button_to to link to a method, can it be done?

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

is it possible to link to a method inside a different model? To execute on button press, or is there another way of doing this, something like an action in a controller?

Method inside staff model:

```
def clearleave
self.where("grade = '1'").update_all(:leave_balance => 22)
self.where("grade = '2'").update_all(:leave_balance => 25)
self.where("grade = '3'").update_all(:leave_balance => 30)
self.where("grade = '4'").update_all(:leave_balance => 35)
end
```

inside a view for a different model:

```
<%=button_to "Clear absences", {:controller => :staffs, :action => :clearleave}   %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails bases on the Model View Controller pattern (MVC). This means, that requests (e.g. trough the browser) are handled by your controllers. Controllers will collect the required data from the models and pass it to the views for display.

What you are probably aiming for is something like this:

Routes:

```
resources :staff do
  member do
    post :clearleave
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
# StaffController
def clearleave
  @staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
  @staff.clearleave # this calls the method in your model
  # here you could redirect to e.g. the show page for your staff
  # redirect_to staff_path(@staff), :notice => "Cleared successfully"
end
```

Your button in the view would be:

```
<%= button_to "Clear absences", clearleave_staff_path(@staff) %>
<!-- not sure if a ", :method => :post" is required here as well -->
<!-- in rails 3 a link_to should also work -->
<%= link_to "Clear absences", clearleave_staff_path(@staff), :method => :post %>
```